# Collection of abstract generic class, raw type warning

Tags: java, generics, abstract, raw-types

I have following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Property<T>
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private T value;

    /*setters and getters*/
}

public class NumberProperty extends Property<Integer>

public class TextProperty extends Property<String>
```

...and a class containing `List<Property> properties`. I get "`Property is raw type. References to generic type Property<T> should be parametrized`". I know why, but I want to have one list of properties of few, known types (Property cannot be instatiated as it is abstract class).

My question is: can I ignore the warning or should I change my code (how?) ?

Comment: To suppress warning: `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Property<?>` if you don't care about which type of object it is this will instruct the compiler that you know what you are doing.

```
List<Property<?>> list;
```

Comment: `?` will make the warning go away and OP can always cast the elements when getting them from the list as the type is somehow "known".

Answer (score 1):

Collections in Java are homogeneous, so it is an error to put values of varying types into them. Note that `Property<Integer>` is not hierarchically related to `Property<String>`—these are two disparate types and the Java type system will not be able to represent your list where some properties are strings and some integers. Your only option is to lose type safety.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a warning, you can always choose to ignore it ;).

The warning informs you that when you have a `List<Property>`, you don't know what comes for the `<T>` in the `Property` class. If you're not sure, you can use `List<Property<?>>` to indicate that anything will do.

Refer to Oracles [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to learn more on this topic.

Comment: `?` means unknown but homogeneous.

Comment: According to [Oracles generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), the question mark (`?`), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type.